# Will objects of a custom class, inside an array, keep their data after serialization?

Tags: java, class, serialization

I am building a small application for keeping statistical data of some sort. I have a general question, before I start coding hard in this matter.

Say we have an object X of its own class, representing a sports match. It has several fields, among which is another object Y - also it's own class. Y will represent stats for a given game. The structure should be something like:

```
class Match {
    Date date;
    String venue;
    ArrayList<Game>[10] gameList;
...
}

class Game{
    int result;
    int blah blah;
    ...
}
```

If I go and create a couple of Match objects, stored in an array for example, i can serialize an object, that contains this array of Matches, but when i deserialize it back, will I be able to keep the data inside the Game objects for example? Do I need to make each class used Serializable?

The reason for my worries are those lines from the JAVA Api [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will
>   be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the
>   class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is
>   serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored
>   from the stream.
>
> When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not
>   support the Serializable interface. In this case the
>   NotSerializableException will be thrown and will identify the class of
>   the non-serializable object.

Comment: `ArrayList<Game>[10]` is bad idea. Generics don't play well with arrays. Also if you are already using collections then why you want to use arrays? Wouldn't `List<List<Game>>` be simpler? Also if you want to let instance of some class be serialized simplest way is to let that class implement `Serializable` interface.

Comment: I know I need to use the Serializable interface. Generally - i know how to serialize a object. My question is more like what happens if this object inside has a an Array, that contains other objects of custom-class type? Do i need to make them Serializable too?

Comment: Yes, you have. The bucket you use ArrayList is serailizable but when it store a non serializable class will came empty after deserialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to make `Match` class serializable. Making a class serialize means that you need to make all instance variables of that class serializable too (notice the recursive definition). In your example, to make `Match` class serializable, you need to make `Game` class serializable.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the term

> non-serializable classes

means such class doesn't implements the serializable interface  there's exist classes in java doesn't implement serializable interface and you can't serialize them  for example `java.awt.BasicStroke` you can't serialize any instance of of this class directly